# ASP.NET 4.0 VB SEO Redirect Issue

Tags: vb.net, redirect, seo

I have an inherited site with a code behind file called "index.aspx.vb" that is successfully passing meta data to the pages. What I can't seem to get to work is URL redirection for SEO mapping (I have to do them one-by-one instead of a simple reroute to the homepage based on status code). When I type in the URL in the Case below I get a 404 Not Found error when I was hoping for a redirect. What am I doing wrong? Here's what I have:

```
Imports System.Web

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    myUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath
    path = "http://www.example.com"

    Select Case myUrl
        Case "/XYZ/XYZ_default.aspx"
            str = "/ABC/ABC/index.aspx"
            flag = "r"
        Exit Select
    End Select

    If flag = "r" Then
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
        Response.RedirectPermanent("Location", path + str)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the resulting URL?

Comment: It stays on http://www.example.com/XYZ/XYZ_default.aspx and shows a 404 Error. I was hoping to be redirected to /ABC/ABC/index.aspx.

Comment: Might need to do some debugging to see if your code is even being called, and if the myUrl is matching.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to work on that now. I'll let you know what I find. Thanks.